# while returning JSONArray from @ResponseBody its throwing error

Tags: java, arrays, spring, elasticsearch, spring-restcontroller

Am fetching records from Elasticsearch via ActiveMQ using @Controller. But while am returning ElasticSearch response as JSON Array am getting the below error in my Postman client

Please find my error below.

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-06-09T06:59:18.755+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.json.JSONObject]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)",
"path": "/document/40011"
}
```

Please find my `@Controller` method where am trying to return JSONArray

```
@RequestMapping(value = DOCUMENTS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JSONArray getDocumentByName(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        System.out.println("Searching documents....");
        JSONArray result;
        result = searchEngineClient.searchByDocuments(name);
        return result;
    }
```

Please find the stack trace :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:312) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
```

Am able to return response as `String` for the below code. But i want to return as JSONArray.

```
@RequestMapping(value = DOCUMENTS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object getDocumentByName(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("Searching documents....");
    JSONArray result;
    result = searchEngineClient.searchByDocuments(name);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the StackTrace

Comment: what is the structure of data that you are trying to retrieve? Is it contain a map?

Comment: Am returning as list from my `Dao` class, in between am having Active MQ integration also. so, am converting `list` to `JSONArray` and sending `JSONArray` to my `Controller`. From `Controller` again i want to return as `JSONArray` where am not able to do that - its giving error

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `@ResponseBody`. It this is a `@RestController` it will be serialized to JSON automaticly.

Comment: If i remove `@ResponseBody` am getting `    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",` and am not getting any stacktrace for this.

Comment: is it a `@RestController` ?

Comment: Yes, it's better to let Jackson do the serialization than use JsonArray, JsonObject, etc... In your case, you don't need to implement a jackson custom serializer / deserializer.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = DOCUMENTS, method = RequestMethod.GET) public @ResponseBody List getDocumentByName(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @PathVariable(&quot;name&quot;) String name) { System.out.println(&quot;Searching documents....&quot;);  return searchEngineClient.searchByDocuments(name); }`